# Jquery get element created with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

after getting data from ajax and create `<div>` element i can not get id from created elements.for example:

My Ajax:

```
$('[id^="view-category_"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var url = "{{ URL::route('get_category_videos') }}",
            category_id = id[1];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {category_id: category_id},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#categories_video_list').html('');
            $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                $('#categories_video_list').append('<div id="choose-video-id_'+value.id+'"'+value.subject+'</div>');
            });
            $('#videos_popup').show();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

`value.id` in `choose-video-id_'+value.id` created by response ajax array now i'm try to set click on that to get id, my below code doesnt work

```
$('[id^="choose-video-id_"]').on('click',function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    alert(id[1]);
});
```

Comment: There generated markup is invalid - at least in the code shown. The closing `>` for the appended div is missing: `'<div id="choose-video-id_'+value.id+'"'+value.subject+'</div>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the elements dynamically. So a normal binding will not work here. You need to use delegates for this..

Also you can assign a data attribute to the elements like this,

```
'<div id="choose-video-id_' + value.id + '"' + value.subject + ' data-id="' + value.id + '"</div>',
```

Then you can get the value id like this,

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="choose-video-id_"]', function () {

    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Comment: thanks sir, problem solved, please let me to accept that

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i dont know, that very bad